Downloading onto hard drive iMac
For a very long time, I have always had my Safari settings for downloads set to Ask for each download so that I could easily download each file into its folder on my hard drive. But ever since a few weeks ago, I keep getting a message stating "cannot move file" whenever I try to download onto my hard disk. I am also met with a message (see the exact message below) telling me to check for locked files when I try to move or copy something onto my hard disk but, after checking every single file, I can confidently say that none of them are locked. I would greatly appreciate any help to resolve this problem as I desperately need to be able to freely download and copy onto that disk. I have an iMac running macOS Sequoia 15.0.1.
The operation can't be completed because some items had to be skipped. For each item, choose File > Get Info, make sure "Locked" is deselected, and then check the Sharing & Permissions section. When you are sure the items are unlocked and not designated as Read Only or No Access, try again.

Let's test a simple fix first. Restart the computer and try again.

Are you trying to save to folders in your user account, or elsewhere on the disk? Is this the one and only user account? Can you show a screenshot of Get Info > Sharing and Permissions for a folder that couldn't be saved to. (Or better yet, unix file permissions in Terminal.)

I also get this using Safari 18.0.1 on macOS 14.7 Sonoma, downloading to the built in drive on my M1 MBP. Interestingly, if I enable my VPN the same downloads complete and are moved successfully.

Check that the folder you're trying to download to has read & write permissions.

How could the OP actually do that, and how does this relate to the error message which mentions "Locked" files/folders?

Hello!! Thank you for helping me! If you would not mind could you tell me how to do that ? I tried to google it but didn't quite seem to understand ? I apologise for bothering, I'm not the best with computers and don't have the easiest time understanding. Thank you for your help though, it is greatly appreciated! When I checked the info of my disk this is it says "you have custom access"
